# How to setup different firebase environments(Flavors) in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, firebase, web, build, flutter-web

I am trying to set up different firebase environments(for example :qa,prod) in a flutter project.

I created two projects in firebase, one for production, one for the qa. Then, in an iOS or Android project, I using separate google-services.json or GoogleServices-Info.plist files.

but,how to do it in Flutter web?

Comment: google-services.json and GoogleServices-Info.plist are for native parts of your application. In the case of web dart code is complied to javascript, so there is no such file in web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this dynamic config in dart code, you can create an interface that represents your configs and create implementations for each environment, so you can change the implementation passing a parameter when run flutter app (using `--dart-define`).

Imagine the case that you have a prod and an homolog environment, you can create three files:

The first one is the contract of your configs, that all environments must have implemented.

```dart
abstract class AppConfig {
 String get baseUrl;
}
```

And we create a class for each environment, with the implementation of the configs defined in `AppConfig`.

```dart
class ProdConfig implements AppConfig {
  @override
  String get baseUrl => 'https://my-prod-url.com';
}


class HomologConfig implements AppConfig {
  @override
  String get baseUrl => 'https://my-homolog-url.com';
}
```

When we need to get the config class, we instantiate based on parameter passed by `--dart-define`

```dart
AppConfig getConfig() {
  const environmentParameter = String.fromEnvironment('ENV');
  switch (environmentParameter) {
    case 'prod': return ProdConfig();
    case 'homolog': return HomologConfig();
    default: throw Error(); // You can set a default environment
  }
}
```

And when you run your app, you just need to pass this parameter, like the example below:

```bash
flutter run --dart-define ENV=prod
```

Or in homolog:

```bash
flutter run --dart-define ENV=homolog
```

**BUT**, if you need to set configs like firebase, you should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560305/flutter-firebase-setting-different-deployment-targets-for-ios-android-and-w/66560306#66560306)

Comment: Thanks @Guliherme ,i am using package info to take package name and set baseurl using package name.In flutter web where i need to update my package name

Comment: @PradeepKumar can you share a piece of the code that you set the baseUrl?

Comment: Thanks @Guliherme ,I have solved with your answer.